# Redirect website to include http://www (.htaccess vanity URL)

Tags: .htaccess

When I type my website's url into the search bar like example.com , the page will load and the url will still be example.com.  How can I make it so that when I type example.com, the page goes to http://www.example.com. Right now when I type in example.com the page redirects to www.example.com (without the http://) using this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code seems to be redirecting from non-existing URLs to the start page ("if it's an existing file or if it's an existing directory, do nothing and stop. Otherwise, redirect to the start page ignoring what was requested")

A more direct approach would be

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

...which is, more or less, a verbatim translation of what you asked ("if the server name does not start with www., redirect to the original resource, on the original server, just with www. prefixed")